# Jmeter and Ant report 90% line

Tags: ant, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am using Jmeter and Ant for one of my project, when we generate report it shows URL, #Samples, Failures, Success Rate, Average Time,  Min Time, Max Time in report.

I want to include 90% time line in the report as well.

right now i am using jmeter-results-detail-report_21.xsl, is there any other pre build xsl file that can give me 90% time line in same report???

build.xml code is given below:

Comment: Interesting. I am also using ant - I never noticed /was not interested with 90% line. i will see and update you if i find. If you find the answer yourself, please share it.

Comment: well i think you shall read this, this article explains the importance of 90% line.
http://koushikarvapelli.blogspot.in/2013/10/90-line-in-jmeter-aggregate-report.html

Comment: It does not mean that i did not know the importance of it. I use JMeter for creating test-data rather than doing performance testing. So those metrics not important for me. Ok..for your issue, did you check this? it looks promising. 
http://www.mail-archive.com/jmeter-user@jakarta.apache.org/msg05400.html

Comment: tried by getting below error 

BUILD FAILED
Fatal error during transformation using F:\loadtest\report\jmeter-results-90.xsl: 
Syntax error in '../[EMAIL PROTECTED]= current()/@label]/@time'.

Comment: please let me know if that worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a custom tool that was designed to be used in scripting/automation: JMeterPluginsCMD.
You can use it to generate aggregate report after the test finishes, using Exec ant task with proper params.

Read this for details: http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMeterPluginsCMD/